# Model.objects.get() or None

Tags: django, django-models, nonetype

Is there a way to accomplish the following in one call:

```
Model.objects.get(id=1) else None
```

The only way I've found a way to do this is by doing:

```
try:
    object = Model...
except:
    object = None
```

Is there a way to do this in a single call in django?

**Update**: There does not seem to be a way to do this other than in a `try/except` block, but here is a better answer: [In Django, how do I objects.get, but return None when nothing is found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090302/in-django-how-do-i-objects-get-but-return-none-when-nothing-is-found)

Comment: Well, it seems you already solved your question. Just as an additional argument, use try: ... except (using specific exceptions) is considered a good practice in Python (let alone Django, which follows more or less the same philosophy).

Comment: `(Model.objects.filter(pk=1) or [None])[0]` is less explicit but sometimes useful also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Django, how do I objects.get, but return None when nothing is found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090302/in-django-how-do-i-objects-get-but-return-none-when-nothing-is-found)

Comment: I don't really like that it's an unnamed except. What's the specific `Exception` subclass involved here?

Comment: it's `YourModel.DoesNotExist` or `FooBar.DoesNotExist`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

How about this:

```
obj = Model.objects.filter(id=1).first()
```

now if no object with id=1 exists obj would be None

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first

Comment: Note that this isn't the same thing, because `get` errors if more than one match is found, whereas this simply returns the first one.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using it in a web request, and you want to return a 404 if the object does not exist you can use

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
get_object_or_404(Mode, pk=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

i think **better to reuse Django functionality** as much as possible, and django has 99% similar func `get_object_or_404` which just raises Http404

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def get_or_none(model_or_qs, **kwargs):
    try:
        return get_object_or_404(model_or_qs, **kwargs)
    except Http404:
        return None
```

**Some tests cases** that shows that code can be used for **Model, Queryset, RelatedManager**

*[in tests one User can Have multiple Contacts]*

```
    @test_for(get_or_none)
    def test_get_or_none_for_model(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user, get_or_none(User, pk=self.user.pk))
        self.assertEqual(None, get_or_none(User, pk=777))

    @test_for(get_or_none)
    def test_get_or_none_for_queryset_and_manager(self):
        contact = ContactFactory(user=self.user)
        self.assertEqual(self.user, get_or_none(User.objects, pk=self.user.pk))
        self.assertEqual(self.user, get_or_none(User.objects.all(), pk=self.user.pk))
        self.assertEqual(contact, get_or_none(Contact.objects.filter(user=self.user)))
        self.assertEqual(contact, get_or_none(self.user.contacts))
        self.assertEqual(None, get_or_none(User.objects.all(), pk=777))
        self.assertEqual(None, get_or_none(self.user.contacts, pk=777))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
model_to_find = next(iter(Model.objects.filter(id=1)), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

get_object_or_404

in your model do . . .

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/blog/%s/" self.slug
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `MyModel.objects.filter(id=1).first()` will not raise an error if more than one model matches the query, which may be undesirable in some cases.

If you want an error to be raised in that case then this is another way:

```
(obj,) = MyModel.objects.filter(id=1) or [None]
```

If there is more than one model that matches the query, then this error is raised:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

But this probably isn't the best way to do this in production. I think it's better to be explicit and use `try` and `except`.