# Django model `get` does not return false

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have an Django app which check if the the database holds numbers which matches the numbers entered by the user in the form. I've managed to get it to redirect to the 'You win' page if they do match but when they don't match it just gives an error saying 'matching query does not exist.' Here's the if/else statement I'm using in the view.py file:

```
if Numbers.objects.get(numbers_win = user_number):
     return HttpResponseRedirect('win')
else:
     return HttpResponseRedirect('lose.html')
```

Comment: What does `Numbers.object.get..` returns ? Are you sure it returns a boolean ?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090302/in-django-how-do-i-objects-get-but-return-none-when-nothing-is-found So you would have to surround it with try except instead of if.

Answer (score 6):

That's because `.get` throws an exception when there are no matches — it doesn't return something falsey.

You have two options:

First, you can use `filter` and `exists`instead of `get`, which will return `True` if something is found, and `False` otherwise.

If you're not otherwise using the result, this is probably the best solution:

```
if Numbers.objects.filter(numbers_win = user_number).exists():
     return HttpResponseRedirect('win')
else:
     return HttpResponseRedirect('lose.html')
```

(As noted in the comments, [using `exists` is faster if you're just checking for existence](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists))

Second, you *could* catch the exception instead of using `if` / `else`:

```
try:
    Numbers.objects.get(numbers_win = user_number)
except Numbers. DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('lose.html')
else:  
    return HttpResponseRedirect('win')
```

As you can see, though, this makes for somewhat awkward code, and it also performs worse than using `.exists`, so you probably shouldn't do this.

Comment: Actually, OP should use `.filter(...).exists()` if all they want to do is verify the item is in the db.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman; corrected

Comment: It will perform better if you assign the result of the get call in a variable and use it in the else statement though, which is probably what the user wants to do.

Comment: @jpic Sure; this is what the "if you're not otherwise using the result" note addresses (in the question, they're not actually using the result of the `get` call).

Comment: Thank you! That does make a lot of sense.