# How to avoid requesting user on login page while using context_processors.py in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I wanted to pass variables with the User information, that is linked to a `Clients` model through a OneToOneField to the `django.contrib.auth.models`, onto the `base.html` file.

So, I created a `context_processors.py` with the following code

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    def userData(request):  
        user = request.user
        u = User.objects.get(username=user)
        us = u.clients.first_name
        uv = u.clients.avatar
        return {
            'u': u,
            'us': us,
            'uv': uv
        }
```

Everything was working fine, until I logged out.

When I try to login again, I get the `accounts/login` url and get a

```
DoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
User matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the object if it exists, or None if it does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090302/how-do-i-get-the-object-if-it-exists-or-none-if-it-does-not-exist)

Comment: Based on your code, it looks like a `User` can have *multiple* `Client`s?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am using a OneToOneField on my `models.py`. So, I believe it can't. By again, I am new to Django/Python.

Comment: @JoãodeSousa: yes then it is indeed impossible. But then it might be better to rename the model to `Client` (models normally are given *singular names*, or the related name to `client`). Since now it "hints" that it returns multiple ones (since `clients` is plural).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your `request.user` *is* already a `User`, so it makes not much sense to fetch it again.

You can simply check if the user is logged in:

```
def userData(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return {
            'u': request.user,
            'us': request.user.clients.first_name,
            'uv': request.user.clients.avatar,
        }
    return {}
```

> **Note**: the name `clients` is *plular*, so that suggests a *collection* of `Client`s. Normally model names are *singular* (so `Client` instead of <s>`Clients`</s>), and the related name of a `OneToOneField` should, if you specify it yourself, be singular as well.

Comment: This worked! Thank you, and thank you for the suggestion about renaming my model!