# Shortcut for getting a single object without raising an exception?

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to simply do the following without raising an exception if the item doesn't exist:

```
User.objects.get(email_address = email_address)
```

Is there a shortcut for this in Django? I just want to check if a user exists with a given email address.

Comment: If you actually want to retrieve a single item that may or may not exist, try this [`get_or_none()` pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512059/django-get-an-object-form-the-db-or-none-if-nothing-matches).

Comment: try [django_annoying](https://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/wiki/Home), supports get_object_or_None and a couple of other fun features...

Comment: @jawache Thanks, that seems like an awesome library. They should include shortcuts like that in the next release of Django for sure, especially `get_object_or_None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the queryset method `exists()`.

From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists):

> **exists()**
>   Returns True if the QuerySet contains any results, and False if not.

In your case:

```
User.objects.filter(email_address=email_address).exists()
```

If there were more than one user with this email address, `exists` would still return `True`, whereas the `get()` would raise a `User.MultipleObjectsTeturned` exception.