# Is there any way to do a Django QuerySet get() like dict.get()?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

When I do a lookup in dictionaries, I frequently use [dict.get()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) so that it won't raise an exception if the key is missing. Even better, I can specify a default value when the key doesn't exist.

Is there an equivalent for Django querysets? It seems like the best I can do is this--

```
try:
    author = Book.objects.get(title='Hamlet').author
except Book.DoesNotExist:
    author = None
```

Makes sense, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512059/django-get-an-object-form-the-db-or-none-if-nothing-matches

Comment: @alecxe: oops, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
books = Book.objects.filter(title='Hamlet')[:1]  # LIMIT 1
book = books[0] if books else None
```

This should be the most optimal way of achieving what you need.

Comment: I don't think it's a good way to code this..

Comment: You're free to propose a better solution—I have nothing against somebody finding an improved way of doing something compared to what I came up with. Anyway, I'd normally just catch `DoesNotExist` and assign `book` to `None` but he explicitly stated he doesn't like that.