# Django saving choices values

Tags: python, django

I want to save selected choice in model.
And I want to use Select widget for choices.
I have a model:

```
qobj = Model1.objects.all()

CHOICE = (
    (x.id, x.name) for x in qobj
)

class Model2(models.Model):
    choice_field = models.CharField("CHOICE", max_length=77, choices=CHOICE)
```

And I got error: "Select a valid choice. 5 is not one of the available choices." - error when try to save.
I was try `forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=qobj)` - No Problem, but I can't get `Model.get_choice_field_display()`.
May be someone know solving of this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by `MyModel` is "empty"?

Comment: As your `.html` currently stands, you're not making use of either `date` or `name` anyway, so you could just remove those lines.

Comment: Empty is i not send a form and changelist is empty

Comment: What is the content of `preview.html` ...is that being rendered directly after the form save (not via the `preview()` view?) i.e. `return render(request, 'WebMamOffice/en/preview.html')`

Comment: You can wait until you have a working answer before marking an answer correct! ;) As it stands, none of our answers apparently solve your problem.

Comment: It doesn't look like the `preview()` view will be called at all?

Comment: I marked as correct for thanks for You, this is not a bad answers and You will get a more reputation.

Comment: Problem in other for me None with .first() not suit, as as other without object. I need object [0] or first() without difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem partial solved in django can't save model choices selected values

Answer (score 2):

Error is here:

```
date = MyModel.objects.order_by('date')[0]
name = MyModel.objects.order_by('name')[0]
```

MyModel.objects.order_by('date') return a QuerySet, if queryset is empty, it has no index '[0]'. Try 'first()' instead [0]:

```
date = MyModel.objects.order_by('date').first()
name = MyModel.objects.order_by('name').first()
```

Case MyModel is empty, first return None
Docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#first

Comment: I query date in form#2 after form.save()

Comment: Got it, inspecting your code, a see you don't redirect to preview, so 
try:
redirect('preview') intead render(request, 'WebMamOffice/en/preview.html')
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: Unfortunatly, with redirect list index out of range. I not understand, i call form.save() before get data[0], why this error. If i have an saved object other going well i can get date[0] of just saved form.

Comment: You override 'save' method or is default?

Comment: default. And in my other models this construction is working well.

Comment: Did You had a problem with datetime field in Django. When datetime field not migrate sometimes?

Comment: You have checked if the object was saved in 'DB'?

Comment: When error no saved. When i change in form.html action="form1" everything is good saved without errors.

Comment: There is the error, when you use action="preview", you submit you form in preview, but, preview don't save nothing, preview only render WebMamOffice/en/form1.html with form, date and name. So, when you use action="form1", form is submited in form1 view, and, form1 view save the object, then you redirect to preview. And I think you need change html from preview view too, change for 'WebMamOffice/en/preview.html'.

Comment: I think next, if i not call date in form.html and date(auto_now(true)) may be this problem will be exist everytime. May be date not autoadd?

Comment: Anderson Thanks so much! problem solved, i change on form1 html and change views as return HttpResponseRedirect('http://www.webmamoffice.org/en/preview'). All is good. thanks. Good Luck!

Comment: If you date field in models has auto_now=True, you don't need to call date, because is set automatically, I still thinking, the error still in action, to execute:
form01 = MyModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form01.is_valid():
           form01.save()
You need to submit you form in form1 view, if you use preview, you are calling
form = MyModelForm()
    date = MyModel.objects.order_by('date')[0]
    name = MyModel.objects.order_by('name')[0]
before save object.

Comment: Great ^^, Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused here:

```
def preview(request):
    form = MyModelForm()
    date = MyModel.objects.order_by('date')[0]
    name = MyModel.objects.order_by('name')[0]
```

You are querying objects, sorting and taking the first item. However, if there are no items it is not possible to do this. Instead use `.first()`, e.g.

```
    date = MyModel.objects.order_by('date').first()
    name = MyModel.objects.order_by('name').first()
```

This will return the first item, if there is one, or `None` if not. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#first) for more info. There are also some [other examples in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512059/django-get-an-object-form-the-db-or-none-if-nothing-matches) for alternative ways to handle this.

However, I would recommend that you *do not use this approach*. When you save the new object (`form01.save()`) this returns the newly created object. You can then access this directly for your preview. For example:

```
preview_model = form01.save()
```

Using `MyModel.objects.order_by('date').first()` to get the 'latest record' opens you to a race condition when another user edits another object between the `.save()` and the select.

I'm not sure of the purpose of `name = MyModel.objects.order_by('name').first()` as this is going to return a completely different object to the previous bit (the first object sorted *alphabetically*) - and I cannot imagine why you would want that. Try something like the following in `views.py`:

```
def form1(request):
    form = MyModelForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form01 = MyModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form01.is_valid():
           preview = form01.save()
           date = preview.date
           return render(request, 'WebMamOffice/en/preview.html', {'form': form01, 'date': date, 'name': name})
    return render(request, 'WebMamOffice/en/form1.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: but i query when form is saved

Comment: ('date')[0] is exist when i query dfate in template #2

Comment: @VolodymyrKirichinets Glad you got this sorted, but see the edits - I think there is a much simpler way to do what you want.

Comment: This problem is solved. But now have other. I want to get values of saved form by id for next template then make some updates. And can`t  choose most convenient variant.

Answer (score 0):

your `preview()` view assumes at least one instance of `MyModel` exists: you're accessing `MyModel.objects.blah[0]`, which only works if there is something at `[0]`.

Comment: I use date[0] after form.save() other words date[0] is exist in theory

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use ManyToManyField:

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    choice_field = models.ManyToManyField(to=Model1)
```